# iCloud key-value storage sharing with other users

Tags: icloud, key-value, sharing

I have been attempting to implement CloudKit specifically for the sharing capability.  I need to share one set of data with a selected list of other user's of the app. CloudKit may be more fire power than I need if icloud's key-value storage can be similarly shared.  I have not been able to find any information regarding that.  What I need to share can easily be represented with one key-value pair.  The 1 MB limit my end up killing this idea but not necessarily.  Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

iCloud KVS (Key Value Store) does not support sharing. Sharing is specifically a CloudKit feature.